# Linux - No Sound After Suspend

Tags: linux, audio, debian, bluetooth, suspend

I'm both using bluetooth headphones and speaker of the laptop.

At first boot, both runs fine and I can change between them.

But if my laptop suspend, speaker doesn't work, but bluetooth does work.

---

I ran `http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh`  script to know what differs on the system. So here is the difference between Before Suspend-After Suspend:

`<` Lines represent Before Suspend
`>` Lines represent **After Suspend**

```
Line: 103
<                       HDA Intel PCH at 0xb4214000 irq 137
---
>                       HDA Intel PCH at 0xb4214000 irq 147

Line: 260
<   Converter: stream=0, channel=0
---
>   Converter: stream=1, channel=0

Line: 272
<   Converter: stream=0, channel=0
---
>   Converter: stream=1, channel=0

Line: 313
<   Converter: stream=0, channel=0
---
>   Converter: stream=1, channel=0

Line: 528
<   Subdevices: 1/1
---
>   Subdevices: 0/1

Line: 543
< Card hw:0 'PCH'/'HDA Intel PCH at 0xb4214000 irq 137'
---
> Card hw:0 'PCH'/'HDA Intel PCH at 0xb4214000 irq 147'

Line: 872,873
<       value.0 0
<       value.1 0
---
>       value.0 3
>       value.1 4

Line: 1116
< uinput
---
>
```

How can I solve this problem?

By the way, here is the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=0x01
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

(I removed them one by one and tried again but nothing changed, so alsa-base.conf is not the source of the problem I think.)

Thanks!

Comment: Look and see if the Bluetooth driver turns off on Suspend and whether an updated driver will fix this.

Comment: Actually there is no problem with bluetooth. I have added it additionally. If bluetooth stays always turn off, this speaker problem still exists. I think it is some kind of "signals are ok but speaker is not powered" issue, because everything seems good, pavucontrol sees the speaker, programs can see the speaker and play music, but no sound on laptop. Maybe a driver issue as you mentioned.

Comment: Update the Bluetooth driver and see if helps with the devices.